# Dynamically change div height with window resize

Tags: javascript, window-resize

I wanted to change height of a div when window is resized. I know it can be done with css using `height:100%;` but that doesn't work on what i need. I wanted to make this happen in pure javascript without JQuery or any other framework.

Here is what i have done:

```
<div id="left">
<div id="inner">

</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left{

margin-top:40px;
width:200px;
height:576px;
background:white;

}
#inner{

height:100%;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.onload=
window.onresize=function(){
var left=document.getElementById('left');
var window_height = window.innerheight;
if ( window_height > 600px ) { left.style.height = document.body.offsetHeight
+"px";    } 
else { } 
}
```

The div with id left has to have the same margin. I just wanted to change the height of div to match the inner window height (in px no %).

Thank You.

Comment: ok i will edit my question now.

Comment: left is object, not value

Comment: i tried but none of my code is working can you give an answer

Comment: @Kishore this is same as I have answered your question is it?pls look or is it needed like this?http://jsfiddle.net/ahneY/1/ if yes I will add as answer please accept that

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan  i want answer for another question can you answer that with this. i wanted to make change margin top change on scroll like in this http://satbulsara.com/tests/ . Watch the yes section on the link. Can you answer with that.

Comment: @Kishore I cant understand your requirement

Comment: when the whole page is scrolled margin top of the left element should change from 40px; to 20px;

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan can i show a fiddle what i want or should i make a new question. I will make a new question.

Comment: No need of new question just make fiddle or explain what you need

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WwfbA/  The red column should stay in the same position only the margin should change to 20 px when scrolling the page. I know this is very difficult

Comment: red has to be unchanged and yello should be changed as 20px margin?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WwfbA/1/ are you expecting this

Comment: no no yellow has to scroll up and red has to scroll 20 px and stop scrolling

Comment: this is the fiddle i gave you. the red section should work like the yes section in this link. http://satbulsara.com/tests/ try scrolling the page

Comment: @Kishore I am struck in another work, if I get the time I will look into that

Answer (score 2):

`window.innerheight` should be [`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.innerHeight) (capital `H`). Note that IE doesn't support it prior to IE9.

Also note that you're comparing an *element* with a number here:

```
if ( left < window_height )
//   ^--- element
```

You probably wanted to get the height from `left` instead, as that condition will never be true.

Comment: @Kishore: I've found a second problem.

Comment: @Kishore: I don't waste my time fiddling about with the browser inconsistencies on dimension properties. I use a good library instead. I recommend it. That lets you focus on the actual thing you're building, rather than the inconsistencies of the platform.

Answer (score 1):

please see jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd3a2/6/)

try to use console.log to know what kind of value or object you dealing with

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function () {
    var left = document.getElementById('left');
    var window_height = window.innerHeight;
    console.log(left.offsetHeight);
    console.log(window_height);
    if (left.offsetHeight < window_height) {
        left.style.height = window_height + "px";

    } else {}
}
```

set 100% first to know the exact height number, then assign back to height.

updated code [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd3a2/9/)

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function () {
    var left = document.getElementById('left');

    console.log(left.offsetHeight);
    var window_height = window.innerHeight;

    if (left.offsetHeight < window_height) {
        left.style.height = '100%';    
        left_height=left.offsetHeight;
        console.log(left_height);
        left.style.height = left_height + "px";

    } else {}
};
```

Comment: no this doesnt work coz the last content of the inner div cannot be seen. i tried this before.

Comment: if quick change if condition < to > to see the result quick. in jsfiddle, window may always shorter than you left object

Comment: if you see there is a scroll bar in browser window also which i dont need.

Comment: I am very thankful to you for trying to help me. But sorry to say this code also doesn't work. In your code if you resize the result area you will know what i was trying to do. This is what i was asking for http://jsfiddle.net/bPsFV/2/ . I made this code yesterday. Thank You so much @caoglish

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for old-school solution that uses debounce based on timeouts, here is what you can do:

```js
function debounce(func, wait = 20, immediate = true) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    const context = this,
      args = arguments;
    const later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) { func.apply(context, args); }
    };
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) { func.apply(context, args); }
  };
}

function updateHeight(div, height) {
  div.style.height = `${height}px`;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(() => {
  const div = document.querySelector('.selector');
  updateHeight(div, 50);
}));
```

Debounce will throttle updates down (by default update will fire every 20ms during resizing). Note you need to update updateHeight arguments and `.selector` to match your div.